# Getting max cells filled number with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, cell

Is there a way to get the max number of user filled cells in an excel sheet without passing a range or iterating through max cells per excel spreadsheet?

right now I have

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Private Sub DoStuff()
      Dim oApp As New Excel.Application
      Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
      Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

      oWB = oApp.Workbooks.Open(txtExcel.Text)
      oSheet = CType(oWB.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

      For Each iCount As Integer in oSheet.Cells.Rows.Count
        'get cell text for every row in a specific column'
        dim sCellText as string = oSheet.Cells(iCount, 1).toString
        'do stuff'
      Next
End Sub
```

Right now the oSheet.Cells.Rows.Count = 1048576 and looking through the sheet there is less than 1000 rows of data.

Answer (score 1):

Try `oSheet.UsedRange`
Here you can check for the column in the `Range` instance returned by above, to figure out cells filled in the specific column.

OR

`WorksheetFunction.CountA(range("A1:A20000"))`